# GLSurfaceView set each pixel to a different color

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

i am new to OpenGl, and i'm trying to write a simple GLSurfaceView that receives each pixels color and updates the view accordingly.
i cant find anywhere how to do this. can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont need to set each pixel of the frame buffer with a specific color. Its bad and nasty in performance. Think about it. You have a frameBuffer of 1024 x 768 pixels thats roughly 786432 different pixel colors!!!!
The best way to do this is to create a tringle of 3 vertices and then give each vertice a color. OpenGL will generate automatically a nice triangle with the color you specified on those 3 vertices.

Let's add some code here shall we ?

```
public void triangleRender() {
    //add the background buffer color you want
    gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
    //clear the buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0, 320, 0, 480, 1, -1);

    FloatBuffer vertices;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3 * 2 * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());            
    vertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertices.put( new float[] {   0.0f,   0.0f, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                                319.0f,   0.0f, 0, 1, 0, 1,
                                160.0f, 479.0f, 0, 0, 1, 1});
    vertices.flip(); 
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    vertices.position(0);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, vertices);
    vertices.position(2);            
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, vertices);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
 }
```

Note that each enable dissable , projection etc are openGL STATES which means that each time the the process is paused or stoped you have to call them again.
Have in mind that this example is not performance optimized which you are not concerend right now.
I would suggest you to study the openGL es states carefully, learn about the graphics pipeline. Go 2d at first (hint study about othrographic projection) and also have a look at matrices like identity, modelView and and viewPort.